# Interception of two objects in 3D space

Tags: vector, game-physics, physics

I am trying to workout the interception of two objects and try to code it into an application

A cannon is in Position **A** and a plane is in position **B**
The plane is moving with vector **b** (without affected by gravity)

A cannonball is shot (affected by gravity) with unit vector **a** and magnitude of **m**

They intercept at position **C** at **T** seconds

*Knowns*: **A**, **m**, **B**, **b**

*Unknowns*: **a**, **C**, **T**

The only thing I can think of to solve it in terms of code is split the equations into X, Y and Z component and substitute T as a value and increment it.

It will be nice if someone can kindly tell how to find one of the unknowns
Thanks

Comment: It is really similar, that question forms a triangle so using Trigonometry is possible. However, since the bullet (or cannonball) is affected by gravity (which forms a curve). I don't see how it can be solved using the same way (with my limited maths skills.)

Comment: https://blog.forrestthewoods.com/solving-ballistic-trajectories-b0165523348c

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in here:
https://blog.forrestthewoods.com/solving-ballistic-trajectories-b0165523348c

from meowgoesthedog